# Radon-Nikodym Theorem and simple function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(S,\sum, \mu)$ be a finite measure space. Let $\sum_0$ be a sub $\sigma$-field of $\sum$.

If $f\in L^1 (S,\sum, \mu)$, prove that there exists a function $f_0 \in L^1 (S,\sum_0 , \mu)$ such that $\int fg d\mu=\int f_0 g d\mu$ for all $\sum_0$ - measurable simple function $g$.

I have no idea how to start.... I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Typographical note: it's better to use `\Sigma` instead of `\sum` for a capital sigma in a context that's not a sum.  It comes out a more reasonable size: $\Sigma$ vs $\sum$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\nu$ be the measure on $\Sigma$ defined by $\nu(A) = \int_A f\,d\mu$, i.e. $d\nu = f \,d\mu$.  Let $\mu_0$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $\Sigma_0$, i.e. $\mu_0(A) := \mu(A)$ for all $A \in \Sigma_0$.  Verify that $\mu_0$ is a measure on the measurable space $(S, \Sigma_0)$ (this is trivial).  Likewise let $\nu_0$ be the restriction of $\nu$ to $\Sigma_0$.  Verify that $\nu_0$ is absolutely continuous to $\mu_0$ (this is also trivial) and now apply the Radon-Nikodym theorem to $\nu_0$ on the measure space $(S, \Sigma_0, \mu_0)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it! By the way, why does $L^1$ matter in this problem?

Comment: @measurehell: Having $f \in L^1$ guarantees that $\nu$ is a finite signed measure.  It would also work if you assume $f$ is nonnegative and $\mu$-a.e. finite; this would make $\nu$ a positive $\sigma$-finite measure, which is still enough to apply Radon-Nikodym.